# JavaScript function loops automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have two functions to clearly explain what I mean.

**Function 1**
In this function if you hover over the square it will start the transition for toggling the class. However if you move the mouse off the element and then back on whilst the function is still going it will wait till the function is finished then it will repeat the function automatically. Whilst this repeat is happening the object is non intractable. For example, whilst it is repeating if you were to hover over it, it will not stay out, it will wait till the function is over and then repeat one more time because you hovered over it. Then it will allow you to hover over the element and interact with it.

```
$(function () {
    $('square').hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass("makebig", 1000, "easeInBack");
    }, function(){
        $(this).removeClass("makebig", 1000, "easeInBack");
    });
});
```

**Function 2**
In this function when you click on the square it will begin the transition of either adding or removing the class however if you were to click on the square before the transition had ended then the function will wait for the transition to end then it will automatically start to toggle the class again. If you were to click on it five times in a row then it would toggle the class 5 times in a row one after the other.

```
$("square").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("big-blue", 1000, "easeOutSine");
});
```

**The Question**
Is there a way to make these functions interruptible?

So for `Function 1` if you were to stop hovering over the element half way through the transition it would start to automatically remove the class or if you were to hover over it whilst the transition for removing the class was going on then it would start to add the class again before the removing class transition finished. And for `Function 2` if you were to click on the element half way through the transition of toggling the class then it would begin to toggle the class again instead of completing the original transition.

**Edit**
As mentioned in the comments below by A. Wolff there is a `jQuery` function called `stop` however as you can see in thie [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Vusa360/sf5q4jv0/1/) it is not very effective as `stop(true)` does not work and `stop(true, true)`/`stop(true, true, false)` almost work however they both jump to the end of the animation and they are both glitchy.

Any way to fix this or improve the effectiveness of `stop()` would be appreciated

Comment: You should try [stop(true)](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: @A.Wolff That actually looks perfect but whereabouts would I put the `stop()` function?

Comment: In you code after each `$(this)`: `$(this).stop(true).addClass(...);` `$(this).stop(true).removeClass(...);` `$(this).stop(true).toggleClass(...);`. Or you could try `$('square').on('click mouseenter mouseleave', function(){$(this).stop(true);});`  EDIT: i'm just seeing a clicked animation could be running while mouseleave event is fired. I'm not sure what is your expected behaviour in this case. Stop only mouseenter animation or both, mouseenter and click ones?!

Comment: More thinking about it, i think it is not really a solution in your case if effectively your are binding `hover` and `click` to same element(s). A jsFiddle would make it clearer i guess

Comment: @A.Wolff I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Vusa360/sf5q4jv0/1/) with all the required information and implementing your `stop(true)` however this proved ineffective as on the hover when the mouse is removed the element just remains where it is instead of returning to the original place.

Comment: @A.Wolff Instead of using `stop(true)` I also tried using `stop(true, true, false)` however this also proved ineffective and was very glitchy.

Comment: In your case, it must be `stop(true, true)`: https://jsfiddle.net/sf5q4jv0/2/  EDIT: oops, looks like you already tested it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113798/discussion-between-dan-and-a-wolff).

Comment: @A.Wolff I tried something very similar however, like your suggestion of `stop(true, true)` when the mouse is removed it jumps out and the starts to remove it. Looking in the documentation `stop(true, true, false)` should stop the animation without it jumping to the end of the transition however it does not seem to

Comment: The thing is that jQuery animation are particulary heavy. I would really suggest for the hover animation, to use CSS solution instead. BTW, because you change pseudo element `:before` content on `:hover`, this makes it glitchy, i guess. The width of element change

Comment: @A.Wolff I understand it is easier in CSS and that it is fairly easy to implement but I would like to be able to do this in JavaScript if possible

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm not able to help you more. Fighting weird jQuery animation is one of my nightmare... :(

Comment: @A.Wolff Alright. Thank you for the help you have given so far. It is most useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to check 2 things:

1. **If the element is still being animated while another event triggers**
   this is a very common practice when using jquery animations that
   trigger from events
2. **If the element is still being hovered (or is not hovered anymore) at the end of the animation, if it's not, set it to the right state**
   This is a special case for hovering animations or other animations that might get stuck into a wrong state due to the "is still being animated" check

If you don't check these 2 things jquery will keep queuing animations while you hover in and out of the element

This should work: https://jsfiddle.net/sf5q4jv0/10/

I have made the "click" animation to stop when another one is started while the "hover" animation to complete before being able to queue a new one, but keeping in mind the 2 rules above it should be easy to animate the items as you please

```
$(function () {
     $('a[href*="#"]').click(function () {
         if($('html,body').data("anim")){
             $('html,body').stop();
         }
         $('html,body').data("anim", true);
         var $target = $(this.hash);
         $target = $target.length ? $target : $('html');
         var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
         $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, {duration: 1500, easing: 'easeInOutCubic'}, 
         function(){
             $('html,body').data("anim", false);
         });
         return false;
     });
});

/*Important Part*/
$(function () {
function hoverIn(element) {
  if(!$(element).data("anim")) {
    $(element).data("anim", true);
        $(element).addClass("hover", 1000, "easeOutBounce", function(){
        $(element).data("anim", false);
      //if it's not hovered anymore it will remove the class
      if(!$(element).is(":hover")) {
        hoverOut(element);
      }
    });
    }
}

function hoverOut(element) {
  if(!$(element).data("anim")) {
    $(element).data("anim", true);
        $(element).removeClass("hover", 1000, "easeOutBounce", function(){
        $(element).data("anim", false);
      //if it's not hovered anymore it will remove the class
      if($(element).is(":hover")) {
        hoverIn(element);
      }
    });
    }
}
    $('nav').hover(function(){hoverIn(this); }, function() {hoverOut(this); });
});
```

Comment: This is a great answer thank you and I will accept it. I just have a quick question about the hover part. When you hover over the navigation at the side if you remove the mouse whilst it is coming out it will finish the transition then it will go back in or if you hover over it when it is returning to original size it will finish that transition before coming back out. Is there a way to make it so it doesn't have to finish the transition before adding or removing the class again?

Comment: Sadly, not that i am aware. The issue is that while animating it sets the element's size as a style, if you stop the animation the style will remain and the next animation won't override it (probably there is some way but none i know of), to achieve that effect CSS would be better

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your help